# Setting per-project indent variables in emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation, locals

My emacs is set to use 2 spaces for indentation globally:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq tab-width 2)
(setq js-indent-level 2)
(setq css-indent-offset 2)
```

But I would like to contribute to a web project (html, css and js mostly) which uses 4 spaces for indentation. So I am trying to set up a `.dir-locals.el` file in the project directory. The file has the following settings (added with the `add-dir-local-variable` command):

```
((nil . ((tab-width . 4)
         (js-indent-level . 4)))

;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; See Info node `(emacs) Directory Variables' for more information.

((js-mode
  (tab-width . 4)))
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; See Info node `(emacs) Directory Variables' for more information.

((js-mode
  (js-indent-level . 4)))
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; See Info node `(emacs) Directory Variables' for more information.

((html-mode
  (tab-width . 4)))
```

But these settings don’t take effect. When I open a .js or .html file in a project subdirectory, pressing tab makes a 2-space indent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the files local to your machine, or are you editing them remotely using something like TRAMP?

Comment: They are local to my machine.

Comment: If you inspect the variables after opening an appropriate file (e.g. `C-h v js-indent-level RET`), do you get 4 or 2?

Comment: Here is what I get:

`js-indent-level's value is 2`
`Original value was 4`

Comment: And you're definitely using `js-mode` and `html-mode`, and not something else (e.g. `js2-mode` or `web-mode`)?

Comment: Yes :-)  I've noticed something strange though: when I open files in this directory, the minibuffer shows a message: "Error reading dir-locals: (end-of-file)". Could this be related to the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters your .dir-locals.el data is unbalanced (`M-x check-parens`).

I'm not sure how that would have happened, but if you can get Emacs to do it, then you should `M-x report-emacs-bug`. I'm assuming it was from manual editing.

I'm not sure whether the *multiple* `js-mode` items is a valid thing to do. Maybe that's fine, but it seems unusual. (Possibly Emacs is confused by the unbalanced parens, though.)

Here's your file re-written to use the more common (or at least the documented) dotted-pair notation:

```
((nil . ((tab-width . 4)
         (js-indent-level . 4)))

 (js-mode . ((tab-width . 4)
             (js-indent-level . 4)))

 (html-mode . ((tab-width . 4))))
```

Please note that (for this specific data) you don't need the `js-mode` and `html-mode` entries, because they are duplicating the default values for the `nil` mode entry.

**Edit:** Experimentally, `add-dir-local-variable` seems to behave as expected once the file is in a valid state.

It prefers creating the more compact list notation where possible -- which is fine; they're equivalent -- but it's useful to be aware of the formatting differences.
See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Dotted Pair Notation` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! Now emacs is indenting javascript as I wanted it to. The indentation of html did not change to 4 spaces though. So, after some googling, I added to the html-mode the following setting: `(sgml-basic-offset . 4)`. It works, but now every time I try to open an html file emacs says that "the local variables list contains values that may not be safe" flagging `sgml-basic-offset: 4` as such value. Do you, by any chance, know of any better way to set indentation for html-mode?